# lambda uuid generator for id's model in rails5 with sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-5, uuid

Since there is no uuid handling in sqlite3 I tried to generate it myself.

Many other posts led me to this:

```
create_table :users, id: false do |t|
  t.string :id, :primary_key => true, null: false, default: -> { "(lower(hex(randomblob(4))) || '-' || lower(hex(randomblob(2))) || '-4' || substr(lower(hex(randomblob(2))),2) || '-' || substr('89ab',abs(random()) % 4 + 1, 1) || substr(lower(hex(randomblob(2))),2) || '-' || lower(hex(randomblob(6))))" }
  ...
end
```

Which will actually generates a default random uuid in the `id` field as fine when you do `User.create ...`.
But when you do `User.new`, which is actually my case in my controller when (via default generated views) I push the `New User` link I have:

- In my form's `id` the value: `new_user_lower(hex(randomblob(4))) || '-' || lower(hex(randomblob(2))) || '-4' || substr(lower(hex(randomblob(2))),2) || '-' || substr('89ab',abs(random()) % 4 + 1, 1) || substr(lower(hex(randomblob(2))),2) || '-' || lower(hex(randomblob(6)))`
- And even if I correct my form options as `form_for @user, html: {id: "new_user"}`, when I submit the form I get redirected to `http://localhost:3000/accounts/lower(hex(randomblob(4)))%20%7C%7C%20'-'%20%7C%7C%20lower(hex(randomblob(2)))%20%7C%7C%20'-4'%20%7C%7C%20substr(lower(hex(randomblob(2))),2)%20%7C%7C%20'-'%20%7C%7C%20substr('89ab',abs(random())%20%25%204%20+%201,%201)%20%7C%7C%20substr(lower(hex(randomblob(2))),2)%20%7C%7C%20'-'%20%7C%7C%20lower(hex(randomblob(6)))`.
  Which also seems to be the value from the field `id` when made via `User.new`.

So I would like to know if there is a way to generate the default value of the `id` field when it is created via `new`, like with `SecureRandom` or something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Erf, the solution was actually pretty simple:

In my `app/models/application_record.rb`:

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  after_initialize :generate_uuid

  protected
  def generate_uuid
    self.id = SecureRandom.uuid unless self.id
  end
end
```

For people who may meet the same situation:

- I obvouisly did not kept the definition of the default value for `id` field (`t.string :id, default: -> { "(lower..."}`).
- I changed the type of the default set of `id` into `:string` (`create_table :users, id: :string do |t|`).

Comment: With Rails 7 (the bug may have existed previously) this no longer works, as `after_initialize` is called every time the record object is created, for example when reading an existing record from the database. You should use the `before_create` callback instead.